# Receive next page of movies from API when bottom of RecyclerView is reached?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm currently working on a project in which we have to develop an Android application that retrieves movies from The Movie Database API (https://www.themoviedb.org/). One of the app's functionalities is retrieving Popular movies from the API and displaying them in a RecyclerView, like this:

[image]

The movies are retrieved from this URL: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=4c422ac80f2c83f42b8f905d4303959d&language=en&page=1

As you can see, there are 500 pages. It's not a solution to load all 500 pages in my Asynctask before displaying the data in the RecyclerView, because it would take way too long for everything to load. Instead, I would like for the RecyclerView to detect when the end of the list is reached, and then load the next page from the API. I have no idea how to work this out.

I am very close to a solution, which is adding an OnScrollListener to the RecyclerView and retrieving the next page if the RecyclerView can't scroll vertically 2 items, but I haven't yet got the logic right. With my current code, once I get near the end of the first page, it will instantly load the other 499 pages, which leaves the newly loaded movies unclickable because the tasks haven't finished yet. I need to get it to work so that once the second page has loaded, it once again checks if the RecyclerView can't scroll vertically 2 items.

Method for building the URL in my UrlBuilder class:

```
    public static URL buildPopularMovieListUrl(int page) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Method called: buildPopularMovieListUrl");

        // Paths and parameters are appended to the base URL.
        Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL_TMDB).buildUpon()
                .appendPath(MOVIE_PATH)
                .appendPath(POPULAR_PATH)
                .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_API_KEY, API_KEY)
                .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_LANGUAGE, LANGUAGE)
                .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_PAGE, String.valueOf(page))
                .build();

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Built URL: " + url);

        return url;
    }
```

MainActivityFragment.java

```
package nl.avans.cinetopia.presentation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import nl.avans.cinetopia.R;
import nl.avans.cinetopia.adapters.PopularMoviesRecyclerViewAdapter;
import nl.avans.cinetopia.data_access.UrlBuilder;
import nl.avans.cinetopia.data_access.get_requests.GenresGetRequest;
import nl.avans.cinetopia.data_access.get_requests.PopularMovieGetRequest;
import nl.avans.cinetopia.data_access.utilities.JsonUtils;
import nl.avans.cinetopia.domain.Movie;

public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment implements PopularMoviesRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // RecyclerView attributes
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private PopularMoviesRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<Movie> mMovies = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_fragment, container, false);

        retrieveLatestGenresFromApi();
        retrievePopularMoviesFromApi(1);

        // Obtain a handle to the object.
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_recyclerView);
        // Use a linear layout manager.
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        // Connect the RecyclerView to the layout manager.
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // Specify an adapter.
        mAdapter = new PopularMoviesRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), mMovies);
        // Connect the RecyclerView to the adapter.
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // Set OnItemClickListener.
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        /* Add a divider to the RecyclerView. */
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rv_divider));
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                for (int i = 2; i < 500; i++) {
                    if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(2)) {
                        retrievePopularMoviesFromApi(i);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }


    private void retrievePopularMoviesFromApi(int page) {
        PopularMovieGetRequest task = new PopularMovieGetRequest(new PopularMovieApiListener());
        task.execute(UrlBuilder.buildPopularMovieListUrl(page));
    }

    private void retrieveLatestGenresFromApi() {
        GenresGetRequest task = new GenresGetRequest(new JsonUtils.GenresApiListener());
        task.execute(UrlBuilder.buildGenreUrl());
    }


    /**
     * Listener class for the PopularMovieGetRequest.
     */
    class PopularMovieApiListener implements PopularMovieGetRequest.PopularMovieApiListener {
        /**
         * Fills our global ArrayList with the retrieved movies and notifies the adapter that the
         * dataset has changed.
         *
         * @param movies The list of movies retrieved by our PopularMovieGetRequest.
         */
        @Override
        public void handleMovieResult(ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Method called: handleMovieResult");

            // Add all movies to our ArrayList and notify the adapter that the dataset has changed.
            mMovies.addAll(movies);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.activity_main_frameLayout, new MovieDetailsActivity(mMovies.get(position).getId()))
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `PagingAdapter` https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging. If you are unsure of how to set it up, you can refer to the codelabs https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/#0

Comment: this is exactly what i was going to post, it my require you to change your code but it does worth it . this is the github link to the full implementation https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Paging-Library-Guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are using raw code to fetch data from server instead of Retrofit library ? Retrofit is very easy to fetch data from server.only API call with object that's it.you can easily paging with library.See here how to implement it https://github.com/square/retrofit